# как считать диапазоны генерации типа( [A;B] и [C;D] )?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

как посчитать двойной диапазон генерации для рандома типа [-4;-1] и [1;4]?
имею в виду эти два промежутка - один диапазон

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [так](https://ideone.com/2HgaqI):

```
(rand()%4+1)*(2*(rand()%2)-1);
```

Comment: а как это получилось?) спасибо, все работает, только я не понимаю как их считать... если можно, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Первая часть дает число от 1 до 4 (`rand()%4` - от 0 до 3, плюс 1). Вторая - `rand()%2` дает 0 или 1, после умножения на 2 - 0 или 2, после вычитания 1 получается +1 или -1 - просто в половине случаев меняем знак...